# 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: No matching constructor found on type 'Resources'

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have added a key in resource file in silverlight project. after building this project and replaced its XAP file clientBin in application it is giving me the following error

```
"An exception occurred while initializing module 'SubmissionRequerimentsVM'. 
- The exception message was: An exception has occurred while trying to add a view to region 'WorkAreaRegion'. 
- The most likely causing exception was was: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: No matching constructor found on type 'CAN.AMI.Contracts.RenewalsSubmissionRequeriments.My.Resources.Resources'. [Line: 22 Position: 40] ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
```

Please help me out from this problem as i am stucked in it and not finding any solution.

Comment: The error message is explicit in showing you the problem. You have no parameterless constructor.

Comment: it was running exactly fine having lots of keyes in resource file. i just added another 1. I am able to fetch its value in ViewModel correctly but having exception at run time. And if i had to add parameterless constructor for that "particluar key" then is it in resource.resx.vb ??

Comment: Resource class already has default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the issue. Whenever i add a new key in resource file in resource.resx.vb file default constructor is changed to Friend instead of Public. so it is causing a problem.
I just changed it to Public and everything is going fine.